# How to run a method which has "KeyEvent e" as it's parameter?

Tags: java, keyevent

Hi Devs I have a problem that how should I call it. If I write "null" in the parenthesis, it gives error that e is null. My code is below for reference.

```
private void myMethod(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        System.exit(0);
    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == e.KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        label.setText("This is aa example");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Main m = new Main();
    m.myMethod(??); //What should I enter in the parenthesis?
}
```

Comment: nothing, that code makes no sense. To work with actions or KeyEvents, you need to attach a Listener to a component. you don't have a component that 'll take one, and you don't have a Listener

Comment: Bro, this isn't my code it is for reference.

Comment: In that case the code you posted here is pointless.

Comment: Yes I know too but this could get me an answer...

Comment: @Creator3301 I aleady told you what you need: a Component on which you add a (correct) Listener, and an implementation of that Listener.

Comment: @Tarmo Dude I think you are taking me for granted....

Comment: @Stultuske Ok I try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with actions or KeyEvents, you need to attach a Listener to a component. you don't have a component that'll take one, and you don't have a Listener